# Using Bootstrap, insert a vertical line in the middle to separate 3 icons to the left, and 3 icons to the right, and still make it responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm hoping someone can help solve a problem I've had for the last 2 days. Unfortunately I can't post an image of that here as I'm new, and have no reputation points.

**I have a layout with 2 sections.**

**1st Section**

First row: Heading (centered)
Second row: 6 icons spread out across the width of the page, and their relevant 1-2 words description below each of the respective icons.

**2nd Section**

First row: 2 Headings (one centered on the left, the other centered on the right; separated by a white vertical line in the middle of the page)
Second row: 6 icons spread out across the width of the page as per the 1st section; but this time, the first 3 icons belong to the first Heading, and the last 3 icons belong to the second Heading.... with a vertical line in the middle, to separate out the 1st Heading & 3 icons on the left, and the 2nd Heading & last 3 icons on the right.

I could get the first line (heading, 6 icons and their relevant 1-2 words description) working in CSS. I used container-fluid, row, and the necessary col-sm-2 classes in Twitter-Bootstrap.

But how do I insert a border-right 100% white line (or any other suggestions will be very welcome), and squish it in between the 2nd row's two Headings and divide the icons into 3x3, at the same time?

The code below is what I used for the 1st section:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h5 class="text-center">HEADER 1</h5>
    <ul class="row">
      <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <img src="img/1.png" alt="icon1">
        <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <img src="img/2.png" alt="icon2">
        <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <img src="img/3.png" alt="icon3">
        <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <img src="img/4.png" alt="icon4">
        <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <img src="img/5.png" alt="icon5">
        <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
        <img src="img/6.png" alt="icon6">
        <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr> 
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

I need the next section to be somewhat like the 1st section, but have a vertical white line in the middle of the section, separating the 2nd header and 3 icons to the left, and the 3rd header and the last 3 icons to the right.

The code below is for the 2nd section:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="row">
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h5 class="text-center">HEADER 2</h5>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <h5 class="text-center">HEADER 3</h5>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->

  <div class="container-fluid section2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <ul class="row">
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
              <img src="img/7.png" alt="icon7">
            <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
              <img src="img/8.png" alt="icon8">
            <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
              <img src="img/9.png" alt="icon9">
            <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </div><!-- /.left -->
      <div class="right col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <ul class="row">
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
              <img src="img/10.png" alt="icon10">
            <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
              <img src="img/11.png" alt="icon11">
            <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
              <img src="img/12.png" alt="icon12">
            <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </div><!-- /.right -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Your invaluable help will be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

***new code for the 2nd section***

```
<div class="section2">
    <div class="left container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      <h5 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-center">
        HEADER2
      </h5>
      </div>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
          <img src="img/7.png" alt="icon7">
          <p class="text-center"2-word description</p>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
          <img src="img/8.png" alt="icon8">
          <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
          <img src="img/9.png" alt="icon9">
          <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.left .container-fluid -->

    <div class="right container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      <h5 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 text-center">
        HEADER3
      </h5>
      </div>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
              <img src="img/10.png" alt="icon10">
            <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
              <img src="img/11.png" alt="icon11">
            <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
              <img src="img/12.png" alt="icon12">
            <p class="text-center">2-word description</p>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.right .container-fluid -->
  </div><!-- /.section2 -->
```

**NEW QUESTION**

Hi... I have another small question...
I was working on the big screen and it wasn't obvious to me until now that I've started working on the @mediaqueries, and resizing the screen.

The icons and the the respective 2-word descriptions aren't exactly centered with each other. The 2-word descriptions are slightly to the right of the icons above.

I've tried using the bootstrap class .text-center on the  element, it didn't work.
I've also tried giving the  a class, and then using "margin: 0 auto" in CSS, and it also did not work.

Where have I gone wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to create a demo of your code

Comment: Hey rhgb, this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/z298f/      Hope it works. It's the first time I'm using it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should consider `.section2` as a *row*, with two children *header1* and *header2*. so add `class="row"` to this `div`, and apply `class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6"` to each header block.

then consider each header block as a single *row*, containing 3 images with description. do same action as before.

`.container-fluid` and `.left` `.right` are no longer necessary, as the parent `.row` and children's `.col-*` take care of these for you.

**Update:** sorry for ignoring your problem with the blank in the middle. it is caused by the default style of `<ul>`, and could be solved by adding `ul { padding-left: 0;}`.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4s8Cr/5/) for example.

Comment: Thank you so much rhgb!! YOU ARE AWESOME! :)   I do have another question though... I've added in .left and .right so that I can put a right-border on .left to create a vertical line in the middle of the page, to separate the 2 sections. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: it is ok to add `.left` for additional styling, and previously I thought you were trying to apply some `float:left` style by adding `.left`. to be noticed that although `.left` doesn't conflict with bootstrap css, I personally would choose names other than `left` to avoid possible conflict.

Answer (score 0):

In your second section make two main rows, these contain nested rows for your headings and respective icons. On the first row add a `border-right`.

Comment: Hey slynagh, thanks for the reply. I've tried what you said, but the headers and icons are not displaying like I need them to. I'll paste my code for the 2nd section in the question again. If you can help to spot where I've gone wrong, that would be great. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The .left and .right should be side-by-side, but right now, the right is below the left. Should I be using some CSS to style this? And if so, any ideas how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: make a jsFiddle and then myself and others can see it in action. Are you trying to put 2 `container`s side by side?

Comment: Also you have a typo. The first opening `<p>` tag in section 2 is not closed properly.

Comment: Hey slynagh, here's the link http://jsfiddle.net/z298f/     Also, to answer your question, yeah I want to put 2 containers side by side, with a vertical line separating those 2 containers. And each container contains a Header, 3 icons and respective centered description.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks much slynagh for your help also!